# Laravel: get the last parent in nested list eloquent recursive

Tags: laravel, recursion, laravel-4, eloquent, recursive-query

I need to get the latest parent in a nested tree with laravel :

Example:

[image: Example]

Schema of the table in my database :

[image]

Relationships in my model :

```
public function parentUnit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Unit', 'unit_id', 'id');
}

public function allParentUnit() {
    return $this->parentUnit()->with('allParentUnit');
}
```

**Question**:

How can I get the latest parent in the picture above:

The latest parent of 
**G is A**

And the last parent of 
**F is B**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a method to the model to find the first parent.

```
public function getLatestParent()
{
    if ($this->parentUnit)
        return $this->parentUnit->getLatestParent();

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: How can I add it in Eloquent Model ??